# how to change values of csv while exporting in php

Tags: php, mysql, csv, mysqli, export-to-csv

I have been working on a database. Now its the final step to export the data to a csv file. I have created the file and it works perfectly. But now the requirement is that the values that are saving in the database can be changed. I have no idea how to approach this. Bellow is the code that I wrote with custom column name. But just say if gender is M, it should export Male in the csv not M. I cannot change the value how it is saved in the MySQL database because the second type of export requires it to be M not Male. and there are many more columns like this.

So please someone who can help me solve this and tell me how can I modify this code to change the values of the columns according to the requirements.

```
$host = 'localhost'; // MYSQL database host adress
$db = 'db_eschool'; // MYSQL database name
$user = 'admin'; // Mysql Datbase user
$pass = 'secretdatabase'; // Mysql Datbase password
$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass); // Connect to the database
mysql_select_db($db);

function cleanData(&$str) {
    if (strstr($str, '"'))
        $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"'; // escape fields that include double quotes
}

$colnames = array(
        'oen' => "OEN",
        'first_name' => "Legal First name",
        'second_name' => "Legal Second Name",
        'last_name' => "Legal Last name",
        'native_language' => "Language First Spoken",
        'birth_date' => "Birth Date",
        'gender' => "Gender",
        'school_number' => "School Number",
        'osr' => "Main School",
        'postal_code' => "Postal Code",
        'canadian_citizen' => "Status in Canada",
        'date_entry' => "Year of Entry",
        'start_date' => "Enrolment Start Date",
        'end_date' => "Enrolment End Date",
        'literacy_status' => "Literacy Status",
        'com_inv_hours' => "Community Involvement Hours to Date",
        'oces_course' => "Ministry Course Code",
        'start_date' => "Course Start Date",
        'end_date' => "Course End Date",
        'credit_earned' => "Earned Credit Value",
        'ft_marks' => "Final Mark",
        'course_status' => "Course Complete",
        'repeated_course' => "Repeated Course",
        'oces_dip' => "Diploma Issued",
        'issue_date' => "Date Issue");

function map_colnames($input) {
    global $colnames;
    return isset($colnames[$input]) ? $colnames[$input] : $input;
}

$flag = false;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT student_information.oen, student_information.first_name, student_information.second_name, student_information.last_name, student_information.native_language, student_information.birth_date, student_information.gender, student_information.school_number, student_information.osr, student_information.postal_code, student_information.canadian_citizen, student_information.date_entry, course_information.start_date, course_information.end_date, student_information.literacy_status, student_information.com_inv_hours, course_information.oces_course, course_information.credit_earned, course_information.ft_marks, course_information.course_status, course_information.repeated_course, course_information.cr_language, student_information.oces_dip, student_information.issue_date FROM student_information, course_information WHERE student_information.searcher = 'y' AND student_information.student_number = course_information.student_number ") or die('Query failed!');
$filename = 'OnSIS_export.csv';
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

// Output to browser with appropriate mime type, you choose ;)
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
$out = fopen("php://output", 'w');

// filename for download
while (false !== ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {
    if (!$flag) { // display field/column names as first row
        $firstline = array_map("map_colnames", array_keys($row));
        fputcsv($out, $firstline, ',', '"');
        $flag = true;
    }
    array_walk($row, 'cleanData');
    fputcsv($out, array_values($row), ',', '"');
}

fclose($out);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_walk` can actually give you the key of the item in the array as well as its value. So you could do something like this in your `cleanData` function where you check the array index and if it's one where the value needs changing update `$str`:

```
function cleanData(&$str, $key) {
    switch($key) {
        case 'gender':
            if ($str=='M') $str= 'Male';
            elseif($str=='F') $str= 'Female';
            break;
        // ... other cases
    }

    if (strstr($str, '"'))
        $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"'; // escape fields that include double quotes

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query, something like:

```
SELECT IF(student_information.gender = 'M' then 'Male' else 'Female') .....
```

Alternately you could create a join table with M and Male row and F and Female row, but that might be overkill.

I'm old fashioned and assuming only two genders.

EDIT: `SELECT IF(gender='M','Male','Female') ... FROM student_information ...`

Comment: Also shortened:  `IF(student_information.gender='M','Male','Female')`

Comment: You can also shorten your select statement by using the FROM clause to specify the table: SELECT FROM student_information oen, first_name, second_name, ...

Comment: oops, wrong syntax (lol): SELECT oen, first_name, ... FROM student_information